# Fully delete data from Clickhouse DB to save disk space

Tags: database, clickhouse

In order to free up disk space, I've gotten rid of a number of old tables in a clickhouse database via

```
DROP TABLE mydb.mytable
```

However, disk usage did not change at all. In particular I expected `/var/lib/clickhouse/data/store` to shrink.

What am I missing here? Is there a "postgresql.vacuum"-equivalent in clickhouse I should be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atomic databases keep dropped tables for 8 minutes.

You can use `DROP TABLE mydb.mytable no delay`

https://kb.altinity.com/engines/altinity-kb-atomic-database-engine

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that. Still the data/store did not shrink after this grace period, but now I guess the tables were not as big as I thought...